# Trocar cor do botão quando clica = gree quando solta volta cor normal?

Tags: java, android, c++

Quero que quando eu clico no Button ele mude de cor e quando eu soltar ele volta para cor original!

Parte do Button

```
public void addButton(String comprar, final InterfaceBtn interfaceBtn) {
    final Button button = new Button(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1);
    layoutParams.setMargins(7, 5, 7, 5);
    button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    button.setPadding(10, 5, 10, 5);
    button.setTextSize(13.0f);
    button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D5E3EB"));
    button.setGravity(17);

    if (comprar.contains("OnOff_")) {
        comprar = comprar.replace("OnOff_", "");
        button.setText(comprar + ": OFF");
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7f0000"));
        final String comprar2 = comprar;
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            private boolean isActive = true;

            public void onClick(View v) {
                interfaceBtn.OnWrite();
                if (isActive) {
                    playSound(Uri.fromFile(new File(cacheDir + "On.ogg")));
                    button.setText(comprar2 + ": ON");
                    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#003300"));
                    isActive = false;
                    return;
                }
                playSound(Uri.fromFile(new File(cacheDir + "Off.ogg")));
                button.setText(comprar2 + ": OFF");
                button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7f0000"));
                isActive = true;
            }
        });
    } else {
        button.setText(comprar);
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1C262D"));
        final String comprar2 = comprar;
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                interfaceBtn.OnWrite();
                playSound(Uri.fromFile(new File(cacheDir + "Select.ogg")));
            }
        });
    }
    patches.addView(button);
}
```

A parte if já está da forma que quero! Quando clico o button ativa e fica verde On, quando clico de novo ele desativa e fica vermelho Off.

agora o segundo que e o else não consigo. Quero que ao clicar ele mude de cor é ao soltar ele volte para cor padrão.

Essa parte que comentei `//button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A2BE2"));` eu ao clicar ele muda de cor, mas quando solto ele não volta para cor padrão!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como voce ta procurando algo direto no código o que acontece é o seguinte a mudança nesse metodo Onclick ocorre quando voce solta o botão, exemplo o botao esta na cor 1 voce pressiona ele e quando solta acontece a ação por isso ele nao volta pra cor 1 pois nao da tempo. entao sugiro o seguinte coloque um listener pra ouvir quando voce soltar o botão e outro para quando voce pressionar, nem vou falar sobre performance aqui estou só dando uma dica para resolver o problema o codigo que segue demonstra como funciona:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button botao;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    botao=findViewById(R.id.button);
    botao.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.cor1));

    botao.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            botao.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.cor2));
            return false;
        }
    });

    botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           botao.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.cor1));

        }
    });


}
```

}

agora aplicando ao teu código:

```
public void addButton(String comprar, final InterfaceBtn interfaceBtn) {




final Button button = new Button(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1);
layoutParams.setMargins(7, 5, 7, 5);
button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
button.setPadding(10, 5, 10, 5);
button.setTextSize(13.0f);
button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D5E3EB"));
button.setGravity(17);

if (comprar.contains("OnOff_")) {
    comprar = comprar.replace("OnOff_", "");
    button.setText(comprar + ": OFF");
    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7f0000"));
    final String comprar2 = comprar;
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private boolean isActive = true;

        public void onClick(View v) {
            interfaceBtn.OnWrite();
            if (isActive) {
                playSound(Uri.fromFile(new File(cacheDir + "On.ogg")));
                button.setText(comprar2 + ": ON");
                button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#003300"));
                isActive = false;
                return;
            }
            playSound(Uri.fromFile(new File(cacheDir + "Off.ogg")));
            button.setText(comprar2 + ": OFF");
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7f0000"));
            isActive = true;
        }
    });
} else {
    button.setText(comprar);
     button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7f0000"));
    final String comprar2 = comprar;

    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#003300"));
           interfaceBtn.OnWrite();
            playSound(Uri.fromFile(new File(cacheDir + "Select.ogg")));
            return false;
        }
    });



    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
       button.setText(comprar); 
       final String comprar2 = comprar;
       button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7f0000"));
        }
    });
}
patches.addView(button);
}
```

Faça o teste.

Comment: Bom Dia! Eu fiquei meio que perdido para adicionar a base que mencionou, pois sou leigo ainda nessa parte. Tem como fazer usando meu pro pio código acima?

Comment: Eu fui ver teu código com calma e fiquei com uma dúvida.Tu só postou o else ai, a dúvida é a seguinte, na parte do if tu ta setando o Onclick no button tambem?

Comment: Se tu puder editar a pergunta e postar a parte do if eu posso editar a resposta mostrando exatamente como deve ser feito.Facilitaria bastante

Comment: Pronto a parte toda do button esta la em cima, e a baixo do código tem o que eu quero fazer bem explicado.

Comment: Nesta parte eu adicionei a cor que eu quero, ao clicar ele muda a cor mas quando solto o button ele continua com a mesma cor                                                    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //depois de clicar vai acontecer isso
           button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A2BE2")); 
           //mas nao sei se entendi bem qual a cor e o nome que consta nele 
           //antes do clique
        }
    });

Comment: modifiquei o codigo na resposta copie e rode e veja o que acontece

Comment: Eu verifiquei e coloquei uma resposta la, muito obrigado!

Comment: mesmo que isso tenha funcionado sugiro que estude uma forma mais eficiente de fazer esta mudança no botão.

Comment: Tem outras formas de se fazer, mas não estava dando certo no meu código.